# Issue with I2C communication with raspberry pi and arduino

Tags: pi-3, i2c, arduino

I am new to I2C communication and python coding so please bear with me if my question is naive or my code looks very bad. I am able to achieve I2C communication between raspberry pi and arduino and able to transfer the sensor data to the master once. However if try to initiate I2C communication the second time I get - "OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor" error. Here is my code below-

```
import time
import smbus
import struct
#Slave Address from Arduinos
SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x04

#Creating I2C Bus
I2C_Bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

weight = 0

def get_data():
    return I2C_Bus.read_i2c_block_data(SLAVE_ADDRESS,0,16)

def get_int(data, index):
    bytes = bytearray(data[4*index:(index+1)*4])
    return struct.unpack("<i",bytes)[0]

def send_data(value):
    I2C_Bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS,value)
    time.sleep(1)

def start():
    while True:
        for x in range(1,2):
            send_data(1)
            x = x +1
        data = get_data()
        weight = get_int(data,0)
        if (weight == 25000):
            I2C_Bus.close()
            time.sleep(5)
            x = 1
            get_input()
        else:
            print("The transaction weight is: "+str(weight))
        time.sleep(1)

def get_input():
    var = input("Enter a number from 1-9: ") 
    print(var)
    while (var != "1"):
        print ("Please select only 1 for now")
        get_input()
    if (var == "1"):
        start()

while True:
    get_input()
```

I think the issue is once the I2C_Bus.close() is executed I am unable to open the I2C Bus again. How can I restart the I2C once it is closed? I have also attached the error that I get when I try initiate the I2C send time. Thanks a lot for you time and help.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/pi/Desktop/weightData_PiMaster_2.py", line 65, in 
>       get_input()   File "/home/pi/Desktop/weightData_PiMaster_2.py", line 57, in get_input
>       start()   File "/home/pi/Desktop/weightData_PiMaster_2.py", line 38, in start
>       get_input()   File "/home/pi/Desktop/weightData_PiMaster_2.py", line 57, in get_input
>       start()   File "/home/pi/Desktop/weightData_PiMaster_2.py", line 30, in start
>       send_data(1)   File "/home/pi/Desktop/weightData_PiMaster_2.py", line 24, in send_data
>       I2C_Bus.write_byte(SLAVE_ADDRESS,value) OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: Why do you close the bus?  Why not just leave it open?

Comment: Hi Joan, I need to connect multiple arduinos as slaves to raspberry, although the current code is for a single slave. And  I need to call a specific arduino based on user selection. I thought we need to close the bus before we can start communicating with another arduino. Please guide me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no need to close the I2C bus.

Comment: Are your devices network-connected?

Comment: Joan, i intend to connect load cells to each of the arduino and only one arduino would be sending data  to the master at a time. The load cells remain active for a short amount of time to send the weight readings. I need to detect when the load cells stop sending the sending the weight readings and close the particular master slave connection. Any other way of implementing this if I need not close the I2C bus? Abolotnov, the arduino and raspberry pi are connected using I2C with Pi as the master and the arduinos as the slaves.

Comment: I repeat (for the last time) - don't close the bus.  There is no need.  Each transaction on the bus has the addressee.